# Bootstrap datepicker disable specific date

Tags: javascript, arrays, datepicker, bootstrap-4

I want disable specific dates with bootstrap

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
    var date_input=$('input[name="date"]'); 
    var container=$('.bootstrap-iso form').length>0 ? $('.bootstrap-iso form').parent() : "body";
    date_input.datepicker({
      format: 'yyyy-mm-dd',
      container: container,
      minDate:new Date(),
      disabledDates: ["2018-06-08","2018-06-10"],
      autoclose: true,
    })
  })
</script>
```

Anybody can help me? Thanks very much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have passed the invalid key. Its `datesDisabled` not `disabledDates`.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    var date_input=$('input[name="date"]'); 
    var container=$('.bootstrap-iso form').length>0 ? $('.bootstrap-iso form').parent() : "body";
    date_input.datepicker({
      format: 'yyyy-mm-dd',
      container: container,
      minDate:new Date(),
      datesDisabled: ['2018-06-08','2018-06-10'],
      autoclose: true,
    })
  })
```

```css
@import url('https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.css');
@import url('https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.5.0/css/bootstrap-datepicker3.css');
.datepicker table tr td.disabled,
.datepicker table tr td.disabled:hover {
  color: #b90000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.2/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.5.0/js/bootstrap-datepicker.js"></script>
<input name="date">
```